# How to communicate between multiple goroutines with for loops with blocking function calls inside one of them

Tags: go, design-patterns, concurrency, channel

I'm writing a Go app which accepts a websocket connection, then starts:

1. `listen` goroutine which listens on the connection for client messages and sends response for the client based on the received message via channel to `updateClient`.
2. `updateClient` goroutine which writes to the connection.
3. `processExternalData` goroutine which receives data from message queue, sends the data to `updateClient` via a channel so that `updateClient` can update the client with the data.

I'm using [gorilla](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) library for websocket connections, and its [read](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.ReadMessage) call is blocking. In addition, both its [write](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#WriteJSON) and read methods [don't support](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Concurrency) concurrent calls, which is the main reason I have the `updateClient` goroutine which is the single routine which calls write method.

The problem arises when I need to close the connection which can happen at least in 2 cases:

1. The client closed the connection or error occurred during read.
2. `processExternalData` finished, there's no more data to update the client and the connection should be closed.

So `updateClient` needs to somehow notify `listen` to quit and vice versa `listen` needs to somehow notify `updateClient` to quit. `updateClient` has a quit channel inside `select` but `listen` can't have `select` because it already has a `for` loop with blocking read call inside.

So what I did is I added `isJobFinished` field on the connection type which is a condition for `for` loop to work:

```
type WsConnection struct {
    connection    *websocket.Conn
    writeChan     chan messageWithCb
    quitChan      chan bool
    isJobFinished bool
    userID        string
}

func processExternalData() {
    // receive data from message queue
    // send it to client via writeChan
}

func (conn *WsConnection) listen() {
    defer func() {
        conn.connection.Close()
        conn.quitChan <- true
    }()

    // keep the loop for communication with client
    for !conn.isJobFinished {
        _, message, err := conn.connection.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break

        }
        // convert message to type messageWithCb
        switch clientMessage.MessageType {
        case userNotFound:
            conn.writeChan <- messageWithCb{
                message: map[string]interface{}{
                    "type":    user,
                    "payload": false,
                },
            }
        default:
            log.Printf("Unknown message type received: %v", clientMessage)
        }
    }
    log.Println("end of listen")
}

func updateClient(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(req *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    }
    connection, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, req, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    wsConn := &WsConnection{
        connection: connection,
        writeChan:  make(chan messageWithCb),
        quitChan:   make(chan bool),
    }
    go wsConn.listen()
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-wsConn.writeChan:
            err := connection.WriteJSON(msg.message)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("connection.WriteJSON error: ", err)
            }
            if wsConn.isJobFinished {
                if msg.callback != nil {
                    msg.callback() // sends on `wsConn.quitChan` from a goroutine
                }
            }
        case <-wsConn.quitChan:
            // clean up
            wsConn.connection.Close()
            close(wsConn.writeChan)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if a better pattern exists in Go for such cases. Specifically, I'd like to be able to have a quit channel inside `listen` as well so `updateClient` can notify it to quit instead of maintaining `isJobFinished` field. Also in this case there's no danger of not protecting `isJobFinished` field because only one method writes to it but if the logic gets more complicated then having to protect the field inside the `for` loop in `listen` will probably negatively impact the performance.

Also I can't close the `quiteChan` because both `listen` and `updateClient` use it and there's no way to know for them when it's closed by another one.

Comment: Why can't you close the `quitChan`? If one goroutine closes it, all goroutines will know it is closed, and then they can terminate. You can replace `isJobFinished` by `quitChan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the connection to break the `listen` goroutine out of the blocking read call.

In `updateClient`,  add a defer statement to close the connection and clean up other resources. Return from the function on any error or a notification from the quit channel:

```
updateClient(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(req *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    }
    connection, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, req, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer connection.Close() // <--- Add this line
    wsConn := &WsConnection{
        connection: connection,
        writeChan:  make(chan messageWithCb),
        quitChan:   make(chan bool),
    }
    defer close(writeChan) // <-- cleanup moved out of loop below.
    go wsConn.listen()
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-wsConn.writeChan:
            err := connection.WriteJSON(msg.message)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("connection.WriteJSON error: ", err)
                return
            }
        case <-wsConn.quitChan:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

In the `listen` function, loop until error reading the connection.  Read on the connection returns immediately with an error when `updateClient` closes the connection.

To prevent `listen` from blocking forever in the case where `updateClient` returns first, close the quit channel instead of sending a value.

```
func (conn *WsConnection) listen() {
    defer func() {
        conn.connection.Close()
        close(conn.quitChan) // <-- close instead of sending value
    }()

    // keep the loop for communication with client
    for  {
        _, message, err := conn.connection.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break

        }
        // convert message to type messageWithCb
        switch clientMessage.MessageType {
        case userNotFound:
            conn.writeChan <- messageWithCb{
                message: map[string]interface{}{
                    "type":    user,
                    "payload": false,
                },
            }
        default:
            log.Printf("Unknown message type received: %v", clientMessage)
        }
    }
    log.Println("end of listen")
}
```

The field `isJobFinished` is not needed.

One problem with the code in the question and in this answer is that close of `writeChan` is not coordinated with sends to the channel.  I cannot comment on a solution to this problem without seeing the `processExternalData` function.

It may make sense to use a mutex instead of a goroutine to limit write concurrency.  Again, the code in the `processExternalData` function is required to comment further on this topic.

Comment: Thank you, it was a great tip to use `defer` and just close the connection from `updateClient`. In addition, it was a great catch to also bring up `processExternalData` because it also has access to `writeChan`.